# How to implement changing a menu's color after it has been selected or focused on

Tags: html, css

```css
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

li a:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="home.html"> Home</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="about.html"> About us</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="contact.html"> Contact us</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="products.html">Products</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="services.html"> Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have been trying to change a menu item's color after it is clicked, so that the user can know what page he is on, but I have been unable to. I have tried several methods I got through google search, but it is giving me the same result: when I press the mouse, it changes , but immediately I release it, the color/background color goes back to the former color.

Comment: you cannot do that just with CSS. try some javascript solutions to add an ' active ' class to the clicked element and style that class in CSS

Comment: Thats because the page is redirected to new URL. Press the menu and release it outside menu, you will see the focus color as you are in same page

Comment: Still trying to get around it, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to add a class active to you element. Here is an example with jQuery but you can do it with pure JavaScript.

```js
var $link_menu = $('ul li a');
$link_menu.on('click', function() {
  // When you click on a link on your menu, it removes all the active class
  $link_menu.removeClass('active');
  // Add an active class on the selected element
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="#"> Home</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="#"> About us</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="#"> Contact us</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li> <a tabindex=0 href="#"> Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

This example could help you to understand the logic. But you have to adapt it if your links redirect to new URL.

In that case, when you load a new page, all the code in current page is gone and all the scripts you have will run again on new page.

This code is not tested since I have to open a new page but you can study it in order to understand :

```
var current = location.pathname;
    $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
})
```

You need to compare the page's url to the links urls on page load.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no knowledge yet on jQuery. I'm just 2 week in HTML and JS

Comment: @davejimm Ok, so what you need to know : I believe it is not possible with only HTML/CSS. You will have to use JavaScript or jQuery (The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript). I can't help you more because you need to learn JS to understand. On stackoverflow, you will find a lot of people who love to help but you need to be able to understand the answers.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it via js and give the clicked element a data-atrribute while clearing the others attributes. In your css, you give the element which has this attribute the specified background-color

#### CSS

```css
li[data-active=true]{
/*do stuff*/
}
li[data-active=false]{
/*reset colors*/
}
```

#### JS

```js
//assuming you use jQuery, but you can easily translate it to native javaScript

$("li").click(function(){
    $("li").attr("data-active", "false")//reset all
    $(this).attr("data-active", "true")// set attr to the one clicked
})
//pure javaScript

let b= document.querySelectorAll("li")
for (a in b){
a.addEvenetListener("click", function(){
    let b= document.querySelectorAll("li")
for (a in b){ a.dataActive,="false"}//reset all
    this.dataActive="true"// set attr to the one clicked
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a newbie; don't know jQuery.